# How join two table in mongodb and select all the details from both table?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections one is order_master and the other one is product_master.
I need to fetch only those order which have the particular product name say 'tops'

Here is my my collection
Order Master

```
_id
o_type
product_data
  ->0
    ->product_id
    ->shipping_details
```

Product_master

```
_id
product_name
product_type
```

based on product name I have to select the order details

for Eg:

Select * from order_master om inner join product_master pm on pm._id = om.product_data.product_id where pm.product_name = 'top'

similar like this

How to write in mongo db

I have tried like this

```
$collection = $this->mongo_db->db->selectCollection('product_master');   
$request = $collection->aggregate(
                    array(
                        '$match' => array(
                            '$and' => array(
                                array('product_name' => 'top')        
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    array(
                        '$lookup' => array(
                            'from' => "order_master",
                            'localField' => "product_data.p_id",
                            'foreignField' => "_id",
                            'as' => "product_data"
                        )
                    )
                );
```

Comment: Just my two cents: MongoDB isn't a fancy version of an RDBMS. If you try to model your data the SQL way and make MongoDB conform to it, you get the worst of both worlds (aside from replica sets, maybe). Read the docs about data modeling carefully and rethink your data model. If you need to join, chances are very high that you overnormalized for your use case.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can "join" "tables" in mongodb using aggregate pipeline but your real problem is filtering documents on its inner array value. In my opinion, You need to unwind the product_data first. Here some reference on unwind https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Basically unwind will deconstruct the array, if Order A has 5 items in product_data then unwind will create 5 copy of order A with only on one of 5 items in it.

After that, you apply lookup then filter them using lookup and do the final step which is grouping on the id to get unique order.

The query would be something like this

```
db.getCollection('order_master').aggregate([
   {$unwind: '$product_data'},
   {$lookup: {
      from: 'product_master',
      localField: 'product_data.product_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'product_details'
      }
   },
   {$match: {'product_details.product_name': 'tops'}},
   {$group: {_id: '$_id'}}
])
```

Comment: This would unnecessarily iterate through all orders.

Comment: given how he models his data i couldn't think any other way though.

Comment: Exactly my point. There is no valid use case for justifying a collection scan. The data model itself is screwed if such a construct is needed to answer the questions.